# Rails model association - users create jobs but then users should accept jobs and get assigned to them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations, one-to-one

Right now I have a model where `users` can login and create `jobs`. Jobs `belongs_to :users` and user `has_many :jobs`. So far so good. But now I want to set up a one-to-one relationship where each JOB can have one user assigned to them. What is the best way to associate the user model and jobs model?

Examples:

1. User can create jobs and a different user gets assigned to it.
2. User can create jobs and assign him/herself to it.
3. Jobs can have no more than one user assigned, but is not required to have an assigned user.
4. Jobs will always have a creator (user_id).

Since I've already set up jobs `belongs_to :users`, there's already a `user_id` column for jobs so how would I re-use that to now show accepting the job / getting assigned to the job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set multiple associations between your `Job` and `User` classes using different foreign keys:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :assigned_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "assigned_user_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :assigned_jobs, :class_name => "Job", :foreign_key => "assigned_user_id"
end
```